# Hide timeout errors in httprequest CLR C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, clr, sqlclr

I have code C# (CLR):

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://sitewait10seconds.com/script.php?param=1");
httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
httpWebRequest.Timeout = 30;
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
httpWebRequest.Abort();
httpResponse.Close();
```

I call this CLR in loop and I would like to close connection after call script.php, because I do not need any response and I would like to call this CLR with next param.
I set

```
httpWebRequest.Timeout = 30;
```

but I get an error

```
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "myProcedure": 
System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
System.Net.WebException: 
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at StoredProcedures.InsertCurrency_CS(.....
```

Is there any option to hide this message and let this code go on?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can ignore a particular exception like so:

```
try
{
    // do something
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex.Message.Contains("The operation has timed out")) return;
}
```

Comment: Apart from that being not safe in the face of different localizations (ie. the exception message is totally different in a different language), you could at least narrow the catch to the type `WebException`. Also, the `Status` property of the WebException class provides further detail on the reason (including `Timeout`).